# Ionic 2 spinner api

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Does anyone know if there is ionic spinner on ionic2? like it is on ionic1 http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ionic 2 Spinner is available in current version(2.0.0-beta.3).

Try `<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>` in your template.

Ionic Spinner Docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/spinner/Spinner/

Comment: This should be accepted as answer, see https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ion-spinner

Comment: Ionic spinner docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/spinner/Spinner/

Comment: Thanks @SteveSanders for adding Docs Link!

Comment: Also for those who wonder, check out the LoadingController which makes it easy to show a modal spinner with a message when e.g. lists are being refreshed in the background.

Comment: its possible to show a ion spinner inside a ion-select  2